# Preperation Failed Error on Centos

Tags: docker, centos, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to use Gitlab-Runner with Docker running on Centos to do some CI shenanigans, but I keep getting the error

```
ERROR: Preparation failed: error during connect: Get 
http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.18/info: open //./pipe/docker_engine:     
The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration 
on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may 
also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

The only Google results for this error are for Windows hosts, but this is Centos. I've also checked whether Docker is actually running (it is)